# too long header for fasta file

Tags: rna-seq

I have a fasta file, like this:

```
>TRINITY_DN100000_c1_g1::TRINITY_DN100000_c1_g1_i3::g.3039::m.3039 TRINITY_DN100000_c1_g1::TRINITY_DN100000_c1_g1_i3::g.3039  ORF type:complete len:100 (-) TRINITY_DN100000_c1_g1_i3:1027-1326(-)
MVWIKFRGLHRVLTSTPLVKSGKTPSQTWAFLDISVELIVFLFLNVHKSPMPHFKIYSEA
FSEEWSLLWLQYSRHLIQKPKPWQIKIELLHLCCCNRLC*
>TRINITY_DN100000_c1_g6::TRINITY_DN100000_c1_g6_i2::g.84365::m.84365 TRINITY_DN100000_c1_g6::TRINITY_DN100000_c1_g6_i2::g.84365  ORF type:complete len:112 (-) TRINITY_DN100000_c1_g6_i2:379-714(-)
MEMMQEIIPFAREMLSARPSKGTMKVYLVGGTFAVLGIVSGMVEAACSLFPEQEESTLTK
LMEDCLTVTAQNQEPQTFIPEDDEQDAEMEAKAKDLPMFRQRRMSFRAHAS*
```

if I want to only keep the second header, like this (the amino acid sequence keep unchanged). which command could i USE?

```
>TRINITY_DN100000_c1_g1_i3
MVWIKFRGLHRVLTSTPLVKSGKTPSQTWAFLDISVELIVFLFLNVHKSPMPHFKIYSEA
FSEEWSLLWLQYSRHLIQKPKPWQIKIELLHLCCCNRLC*
>TRINITY_DN100000_c1_g6_i2
MEMMQEIIPFAREMLSARPSKGTMKVYLVGGTFAVLGIVSGMVEAACSLFPEQEESTLTK
LMEDCLTVTAQNQEPQTFIPEDDEQDAEMEAKAKDLPMFRQRRMSFRAHAS*
```

I know a command

```
> sed 's/::.*//' input > output
```

can only keep the first header `>TRINITY_DN100000_c1_g1` if I want to keep the second header with the isoform information `>TRINITY_DN100000_c1_g1_i3`, how should I correct this command?

Comment: You can also do this via eFetch or Biopython directly without regex-ing

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way:

```
$ sed -E 's/>[^:]*::([^:]*)::.*/>\1/' file.fa 
>TRINITY_DN100000_c1_g1_i3
MVWIKFRGLHRVLTSTPLVKSGKTPSQTWAFLDISVELIVFLFLNVHKSPMPHFKIYSEA
FSEEWSLLWLQYSRHLIQKPKPWQIKIELLHLCCCNRLC*
>TRINITY_DN100000_c1_g6_i2
MEMMQEIIPFAREMLSARPSKGTMKVYLVGGTFAVLGIVSGMVEAACSLFPEQEESTLTK
LMEDCLTVTAQNQEPQTFIPEDDEQDAEMEAKAKDLPMFRQRRMSFRAHAS*
```

The idea is to match a `>`, then as many non`:` as possible (`[^:]*`), and then capture the string between the first `::` and the second `::`. Finally, you replace the entire line with the captured string.

Once you're satisfied this does what you need, you can edit the original file with `-i`:

```
sed -i -E 's/>[^:]*::([^:]*)::.*/>\1/' file.fa
```

---

Alternatively, set `awk`'s field separator to `::` and print the second field only on lines that start with `>`:

```
$ awk -F'::' '/^>/ ? $0=">"$2 : 1' file.fa 
>TRINITY_DN100000_c1_g1_i3
MVWIKFRGLHRVLTSTPLVKSGKTPSQTWAFLDISVELIVFLFLNVHKSPMPHFKIYSEA
FSEEWSLLWLQYSRHLIQKPKPWQIKIELLHLCCCNRLC*
>TRINITY_DN100000_c1_g6_i2
MEMMQEIIPFAREMLSARPSKGTMKVYLVGGTFAVLGIVSGMVEAACSLFPEQEESTLTK
LMEDCLTVTAQNQEPQTFIPEDDEQDAEMEAKAKDLPMFRQRRMSFRAHAS*
```

Answer (score 1):

A 2 step workaround is:

1. Get rid of everything after the piece of info you want, that is anything starting with `::` and goes on with `g`:

   `sed "s/::g.*//" fasta > fasta2`

`>TRINITY_DN100000_c1_g1::TRINITY_DN100000_c1_g1_i3`

2. Get rid of the "first header" as you call it, after the first step, it is rather straightforward:

   `sed "s/>TRINITY_.*::/>/" fasta2 > fasta3`

`>TRINITY_DN100000_c1_g1_i3`

EDIT:

@terdon showed that multiple `sed` commands can be used when separated by `;` in GNU `sed` (default on Linux):

```
sed "s/::g.*//; s/>TRINITY_.*::/>/" fasta > modified_fasta
```

Comment: it worked!! thank you!

Comment: There is no need for multiple steps: `sed 's/::g.*//; s/>TRINITY_.*::/>/'`. Or, if you don't have GNU `sed`: `sed -e 's/::g.*//' -e 's/>TRINITY_.*::/>/'`. You could even pipe one `sed` into another, that would at least avoid the temp files: `sed 's/::g.*//' | 
 sed 's/>TRINITY_.*::/>/'`.